# SQL case statement, filter by date, group by id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: transactions and currency. Transactions table contains transactions:

```
id     date           client_id     currency     amount
2      '2017-07-18'   29            'EURO'       340
3      '2018-08-09'   34            'RUB'        5000
```

Currency table contains currency exchange rates EURO or USD to RUB - 1st row for example means that 1 EURO = 70 RUB. For weekends the are no values as banks are closed and for calculations I need to use Friday exchange rates:

```
date           currency     value
'2017-08-07'   'EURO'       70
'2018-08-07'   'USD'        60
'2018-09-09'   'USD'        NULL
```

So I need to calculate amount spent by every client in RUB. And if possible not use window functions.

I tried to use `case when` and `group by` client_id but then I need to consider currency rates every time they made a transaction and I don't know how to provide for that.

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.*, amount * coalesce((select value 
                                from currency c 
                               where c.currency = t.currency 
                                 and c.date <= t.date order by c.date desc limit 1),
                              1)
  from transactions t
```

Assumes if no currency is found it is RUB so it uses 1 as exchange rate.

Comment: `select` inside `coalesce` should be in parentheses: `coalesce((select ...), 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can express this with a lateral join:

```
select t.*,
       t.amount * c.value as rub
from transactions t left join lateral
     (select c.*
      from currency c
      where c.currency = t.currency and
            c.value is not null and
            c.date <= t.date
      order by c.date desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) c;
```